# Application/Octed-Stream header for XML file

Tags: header

My application when downloading XML file returns headers:

```
Content-Type: Application/Octed-Stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xml
```

Is this behavior correct form security point of view or it should be specified that this is XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that MIME ("Application/Octet-Stream"), used with the Content-Disposition header, simply makes sure that browsers download the url instead of displaying it in the browser. There should not be any security implications of such a configuration. If you want to be able to view the URL online in the browser you can change it's type to "text/xml" or "application/xml".

Comment: The correct header to instruct browsers to download the content is `Content-Disposition: attachment` and not `Content-type`.  There are browser quirks which would also interpret `application/octet-stream` as `text/html`, notably IE. I'd suggest using correct Content-type header along with Content-disposition. And, not to forget `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`, just in case.